# automation in scraping multiple pages with known url scheme

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, anaconda, urllib

I am having trouble in scraping a list of hits. 
For each year there is a hit list in a certain webpage with a certain url. The url contains the year so I'd like to make a single csv file for each year with the hit list.

Unfortunately I cannot make it sequentially and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: 'h'
```

Here is the code I am trying to use. I apologize if there are simple mistakes but I'm a newbie in pyhon and I couldn't find any sequence in the forum to adapt to this case.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
years = list(range(1947,2016))

for year in years:
    my_urls = ('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm')
    my_url = my_urls[0]
    for my_url in my_urls:
        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        html_input = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_input, "html.parser")
        container = page_soup.findAll("li")
        filename = "singoli" + str(year) + ".csv"
        f = open(singoli + str(year), "w")
        headers = "lista"
        f.write(headers)
        lista = container.text
        print("lista: " + lista)
        f.write(lista + "\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: sorry. I just noticed I pasted an old version of the code where there was an easy mistake, Instead of  lista = container[0].text I wrote  lista = container.text

Comment: You can use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46100207/edit) button to make changes to your question.

Comment: thanks. I couldn't find it in the question, but only in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You think you are defining a tuple with `('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm')` but you just defined a simple string.

So you are looping in a string, so looping letter by letter, not url by url.

When you want to define a tuple with one single element you have to explicit it with a ending `,`, example: `("foo",)`.

Fix:

```
my_urls = ('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm', )
```

---

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but
>   effective.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! it's working now!!!! I just have an issue since i cannot understand why it works just for 1947-1954 and not afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will solve the issue:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open("hitparade.csv","w",newline='',encoding='utf8')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for year in range(1947,2016):
    my_urls = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.hitparadeitalia.it/hp_yends/hpe' + str(year) + '.htm').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(my_urls, "lxml")
    [scr.extract() for scr in soup('script')]
    for container in soup.select(".li1,.liy,li"):
        writer.writerow([container.text.strip()])
        print("lista: " + container.text.strip())
outfile.close()
```